# arm-none-eabi-g++: command not found in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, g++, scons

I'm attempting to build firmware from a GitHub project, which uses GCC-ARM, SCons, and OpenOCD (I'm using a Mac btw). If I run "scons" from the command line, the project builds just fine.

However, I want to use Eclipse to build the project. I installed "SConsolidator" and "GNU ARM on Eclipse" plugins, and I imported the project as a Scons project. I also went into project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols and I added the GNU ARM includes directory for GNU C and GNU C++ under the includes tab.

[image: Pic of GNU ARM includes directory being added]
However, when I try to build the project, I get this:

```
=== Running SCons at 10/5/16 10:04 PM ====
Command line: /usr/local/bin/scons -u --jobs=8
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: building associated VariantDir targets: build/lpc11c14 build/lpc1549 build
CXX     build/BMS/src/ADT7470Fan.o
sh: arm-none-eabi-g++: command not found
CXX     build/BMS/src/main.o
sh: arm-none-eabi-g++: command not found
CXX     build/BMS/src/peripherals.o
sh: arm-none-eabi-g++: command not found
CXX     build/BMS/src/pins.o
sh: arm-none-eabi-g++: command not found
CXX     build/Cutoff/src/main.o
sh: arm-none-eabi-g++: command not found
CXX     build/Cutoff/src/peripherals.o
sh: arm-none-eabi-g++: command not found
CXX     build/Cutoff/src/pins.o
sh: arm-none-eabi-g++: command not found
scons: *** [build/BMS/src/ADT7470Fan.o] Error 127
CXX     build/Dashboard/src/can_dash.o
scons: *** [build/BMS/src/main.o] Error 127
scons: *** [build/BMS/src/peripherals.o] Error 127
scons: *** [build/BMS/src/pins.o] Error 127
scons: *** [build/Cutoff/src/main.o] Error 127
scons: *** [build/Cutoff/src/peripherals.o] Error 127
scons: *** [build/Cutoff/src/pins.o] Error 127
sh: arm-none-eabi-g++: command not found
scons: *** [build/Dashboard/src/can_dash.o] Error 127
scons: building terminated because of errors.
Duration 9132 ms.
```

I'm following the instructions on the Github's page, and it works for other people, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I suspect it has to do with the $PATH not registering for Eclipse, since I added /usr/local/gcc-arm-none-eabi-5_4-2016q3/bin to the $PATH using ~/.bash_profile so "scons" would work in command line.

Comment: (just guess without really knowing scons or Eclipse that well) May it be the scons running from Eclipse is using real `sh` (or what is at mac set as default replacement, as old `sh` is rarely used, but that error message...), while you're using `bash`, so starting it from CLI has your .bash_profile used? The include path are completely unrelated to this, the error is about `sh` being unable to find g++ binary (for particular architecture+ABI). Maybe check if scons can be configured to use bash, or how to set path for sh as well upon login, or install that arm gcc globally at system level?

Comment: I found out through http://gnuarmeclipse.github.io/toolchain/path/ that the error is caused by Eclipse not finding the toolchain path. Unfortunately, I don't know how to set this in Eclipse. I thought setting $PATH was enough.

Comment: I realized that I think I solved this, but it was a while ago. I'm running Eclipse on a Mac, and I believe I just had to open Eclipse from terminal (using open Eclipse.app) to get it to register the $PATH.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable running 32 bit binaries on your 64 bit userland.

For debian:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386
```